# Best way to Setup Cloudwatch in 'n' number of servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-opsworks

We want to setup cloudwatch in more that 50 servers for which in general we will have to do it manually logging into each server.But we would like to reduce the manual work.
While browsing through we found below two ideas:

1)Opswork( aws internally uses chef)

2) Chef

Are the above approaches correct to achieve what intend to? 
Which approach is best suitable?

Your suggestions will be of great help... Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "setup cloudwatch"? Are you installing software that sends custom metrics to Amazon CloudWatch? Have you considered using the [Amazon EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/)?

Comment: By setup i mean setting up of log agent and configuring the log agent file as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

We performed this activity using chef.The process was simple.
There are a number of cookbooks already available on the chef supermarket which is of great help to beginners.
We did not try Opswork so i will not be able to comment which is a better approach.